# How can I realize a swipe action via a button click in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager

I am using a viewpager and two fragments. You can swipe between those fragments. Now, how can I implement a button that simulates this swipe gesture on click.
Basically, I want to switch to the other fragment on a button click.

How can I do that?

Comment: Simply start one fragment from another on button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the current fragment inside the onClickListner of the button you have created:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(n);
```

Where **n** is the fragment number in the FragmentPagerAdapter.